# Is it correct to use Autofac IComponentContext in controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, containers, asp.net-core-webapi, autofac

I connected Autofac to my ASP.NET CORE WEB-API application.
Registered two implementations of IService in the container by keys (enum). 
Through the IComponentContext container, using the key, I get one of the implementations in the Get method of the controller (BotController):
_container.ResolveKeyed  ((ServiceEnum) serviceType).

I read on the forum that it is not correct to use IComponentContext. 
Questions:
-1. Why is it wrong?
-2. If not correct how can I resolve Named and Keyed implementations?

Example controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/message/update")]
public class BotController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMainDbConnection _connection;
    private readonly IComponentContext _container;

    public BotController(IMainDbConnection connection, IComponentContext container)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _container = container;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(int serviceType)
    {
        var service = _container.ResolveKeyed<IService>((ServiceEnum) serviceType);
        var result = service.Get(serviceType.ToString());
        
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

Comment: @TravisIllig 
Yes, I read this post.
So the problem is only in the design?
Or are there performance issues?

Comment: Correct. It's not a performance issue.

Comment: You could register a delegate factory instead of injecting `IComponentContext` https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html